# Couldn't able to post the data in reactjs (showing 400 BAD REQUEST)

Tags: reactjs

my objective is to send the data but it is showing 400 BAD REQUEST, i don't know where i'm going wrong. I know it's a small thing but couldn't able to figure it out where i'm going wrong.

Here is the API format:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "class": "string",
  "count": 0,
  "students": [
    {
      "studentsId": "string",
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote in this way:

```
let obj = {
            "id": this.state.id,
            "class": this.state.sclass,
            "count": this.state.classStud.length,
            "studentsId": this.state.classStud.map(stud=> stud.id)
        }
axios.post(`/api/Students`, obj, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

classStud JSON data would be in this format:

```
email: "abc@gmail.com"
class: null
id: "45wer154587jh87"
name: "AB C"
```

Can anyone help me where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request data is not in accordance with the API format which is why you get 400 BAD REQUEST.

You need to sent students data as an array of object with each object having key as `studentsId`. You can change how you prepare you data like below

```
  let obj = {
        "id": this.state.id,
        "class": this.state.name,
        "count": this.state.classStud.length,
        "students": this.state.classStud.map(stud=> ({stundentsId: stud.id}))
    }
```

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line

```
   "studentsId": this.state.classStud.map(stud=> stud.id)
```

to this

```
"students": this.state.classStud.map(stud=> {
  return {
    "studentsId" :stud.id
 }
})
```